# Javascript .push method returning an error

Tags: javascript, variables, methods

So I am trying to push a new variable onto an array every time a function is called, but the console keeps returning an error for some reason.

```
let originalItem = {}

function storeItemById(rewriteItemId) {
  let pushItem = rewriteItemId;

  originalItem.push(pushItem);

  console.log(originalItem);
}
```

So what I'm trying to do here is push the value of rewriteItemId into the array of originalItem, then log all the values assigned to originalItem to the console. I can simulate a value by typing and entering storeItemById('random value') into the console, but when I do, I get this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: originalItem.push is not a function
```

Any help would be appreciated, and also please note that I am a novice coder. Thanks.

Comment: `.push()` is a method on the Array prototype. You've got an object, not an array.

Comment: Change `let originalItem = {}` to `let originalItem = []`

Comment: Or add key-value pairs, if you want to use an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seem that your trying to call `push` onto an Object.

this might be why your having a typeError.

ether change
`let originalItem = {}`
to
`let originalItem = [];`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating object.
Instead, create array like this

```
let originalItem = []
```